# Raw Clone system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, fork, system-calls

I am trying to use the raw clone system, but I could not find any proper documentation. 
I tried to write a small program to try it, but this ends up with a segmentation fault.

I cannot understand where I am wrong.

here is the small application :

```
define STACK_SIZE 0x10000
define BUFSIZE 200

#define _GNU_SOURCE

void hello (){
    fprintf(stderr,"Hello word\n"); 
    _exit(0); 
}


int main()  
{

int res; 
void *stack = mmap(0, STACK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  pid_t ptid, tid; 

  printf("Stack %p\n", stack + STACK_SIZE);
  memset(stack, 0, STACK_SIZE); 

  res= syscall(SYS_clone,CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_FS|CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES,stack + STACK_SIZE, &tid,&ptid,NULL );

  if (!res)
      hello(); 

  printf("Clone result %x\n", res); 
  waitpid(-1, NULL, __WALL); 

 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `clone` syscall (essentially reserved for thread libraries implementor). Use the `pthread` library.

Comment: I need to use it because I am working with system calls.

Comment: The you also need the `futex` syscall, which require some machine-specific assembly code. You should explain why you cannot use pthreads and you should dive into the kernel source code to understand what is happenning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't say I recommend going with clone if you can use pthreads. I've had bad experience with functions such as malloc() in relation to clone.

Have you looked at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) for documentation?

Here is an example that runs for me. I didn't really examine your code to see why it might be crashing.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

// Allow us to round to page size
#define ROUND_UP_TO_MULTIPLE(a,b) \
( ( (a) % (b) == 0) ? (a) : ( (a) + ( (b) - ( (a) % (b) ) ) ) )

struct argsy {
    int threadnum;
};

int fun(void * args) {
    struct argsy * arguments = (struct argsy *) args;
    fprintf(stderr, "hey!, i'm thread %d\n", arguments->threadnum);
    return 0;
}

#define N_THREADS 10
#define PAGESIZE 4096

struct argsy arguments[N_THREADS];

int main() {
    assert(PAGESIZE==getpagesize());

    const int thread_stack_size = 256*PAGESIZE;
    void * base = malloc((((N_THREADS*thread_stack_size+PAGESIZE)/PAGESIZE)*PAGESIZE));
    assert(base);
    void * stack = (void *)ROUND_UP_TO_MULTIPLE((size_t)(base), PAGESIZE);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) { 
        void * args = &arguments[i];
        arguments[i].threadnum = i;
        clone(&fun, stack+((i+1)*thread_stack_size), 
            CLONE_FILES | CLONE_VM,
            args);
    }

    sleep(1);

    // Wait not implemented
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `strace` command on this program, so you could see what arguments go into the "raw clone" system call underneath this clone call. Then see what is different between it and your call.

Answer (score -1):

The child pops the return address from the empty stack, reading from an unmapped address.

**NB:** The answer assumes x86_64 ISA, where `call` places the return address on a stack. Contrast it with AArch64, where the Link Register may hold the return address instead.

### Details

According to the man page for `clone`, "execution in the child continues from the point of the call". Yet, although the child and the parent initially execute the same instructions, they don't share the stack, and a `ret` instruction behaves differently in the parent and child.

Running the application under GDB reveals that SIGSEGV occurs in the `syscall` function at `ret` instruction.

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to LWP 415]
syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:40
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7ee0745 <syscall+37>: retq
```

`ret` pops the return address from the stack. The child, with its empty stack, fails to execute it, while the parent successfully returns to the `main` function.

You can fix the unmapped access by supplying `stack + STACK_SIZE - 8` as the third syscall argument. However, the underlying problem remains: the zero-initialized stack doesn't store the return address. The following image illustrates the problem .

[image: simplified syscall]
`syscall+...`  means "somewhere in syscall", so as not to clutter the scheme with addresses.

### Solution

Macattack's answer already mentioned the wrapper for the clone. Implement the arch-specific wrapper in the vein of the [uclibc](https://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/sysdeps/linux/x86_64/clone.S) one.

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide a working Go code.